# Is there software that can determine whether I speak with a neutral accent?

Tags: learning, accent

I have a query regarding enhancing my accent. I am searching for software in which I speak a paragraph and it compares my speech to find out whether it is accent-free or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which specific accent are you looking to improve?

Like [this website illustrates](http://www.ling.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/Home/HomeMainFrameHolder.htm), there are many of them!

> provide an overview of the variety of the sounds of the English language on various levels:
>
> - **in time**, with our transcriptions of historical ancestor forms of English, from present-day back to Late Modern English, Early Modern, Middle and Old English, as far back even as Proto-Germanic;
> - over geographical space;
> - by sociolinguistic context.

That being said, you can try some online resources:

- [howjsay.com](http://www.howjsay.com/)
- [fonetiks.org](http://www.fonetiks.org/)
- [acapela-group](http://www.acapela-group.com/text-to-speech-interactive-demo.html): its Text to Speech Demo allows you to listen to a small selection of different accents.

Comment: Yes, there are many standard dialects of English, which is presumably what the poster means by "accent free". Of course we all have accents of one kind or another.

Answer (score 3):

Livemocha is a platform to study foreign languages. For its spoken language module you record yourself speaking and other users on the site provide feedback.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing, in English, as a neutral accent. Every accent gives some idea about the person speaking. Even so called 'neutral accents' do so too. Really all you should wish to do is either polish off some of the rougher edges of your own accent or choose a new accent that you like, one that you think is beautiful or reflects your character, and try to practice it.

In the past I have tried out some computerised speech tutors with my students. In general I have been unimpressed by the methods or results.

Comment: Both true and interesting, but I can't upvote this because it's not an answer to the question asked.  (If everyone around you shares one accent, how can you 'polish off the edges?)

Answer (score 3):

There's a small, English city called Peterborough that's considered to have a neutral accent. It became the UK's Call Centre Capital because businesses felt that people would prefer a neutral accent and that Peterborough had one.

I'm not sure how they decided what a neutral accent sounded like, or why they thought people would prefer it, but that was what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Software - not sure about that but you could tune your accent by ear. Many American TV showns seems to use a homogomised accent, pick one and compare yourself against that. Avoid "the Wire" (I still need subtitles for that one) or anything with NYC gangsters.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a program that would tell you if you are accent-free? You cannot be accent free. Everyone has an accent if we want it or not. 
You can speak 'standard' language ( with correct textbook grammar ) but you will always not matter what have an accent.

Maybe precise what do you mean by 'accent-free'?  Free from the accent you live in? Free from the accent you work within? 
Even if you learn how to speak with a different accent perceived as normal, you would have an accent and won't be accent free according to people who have different accent.

It's a bit a of Sisyphean task to be honest.

Comment: If there was some way that a person could speak perfect English, without an accent, they'd sound like a psychopath anyway.

Comment: @CarlSmith True. All those English people sound crazy.

Comment: I'm an English person, and we all have accents. I live in Peterborough, which became call-centre capital because it has a neutral accent. But we still do have accents. It sounds a bit like a farmer that thinks he's from London.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's relatively easy to 'polish off' an American accent — no offense intended, I'm American. But we drop the 'g's at the end of infinitives and say *walkin'* and *talkin'* rather than *walking* and *talking*. Adding 'g's to our words would polish off or maybe polish up an accent.

We use 'd' in words that have 't' — say, *Peter*, which is pronounced 'Peder'. Any American would sound strange or possibly British if they'd pronounce it as 'Peter' instead. We also pronounce the words *medal* and *metal* the same.

And if anyone would drop the *gonna* and instead say 'going to' it would polish up if not off the accent.

But the person who posed this question doesn't say what their first language is or what kind of an accent they have that they'd like to alter.

Comment: Those aren’t infinitives, and everyone says that.